# Best API for simple 2D graphics with Java

Tags: java, graphics, java-2d

I'm not sure what the best api for simple 2d graphics with Java is. I know `java.awt.Graphics2D` was the standard but has it been replaced? Swing is the new API for Java GUI apps but it seems a bit heavy for what I want. What I really want is something like the C [SDL library](http://libsdl.org/).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[Java 2D](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/) (`Graphics2D` and friends) is indeed the best choice that I know of. Swing is actually implemented on top of Java 2D, so yes, if you want non-GUI-type graphics, Java 2D is the way to go.

Comment: Original link was dead, I updated it to point to the new Java 2D tutorials at Oracle's site.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have the least work possible if you're building a game (or even if not) use http://slick.cokeandcode.com/

UPDATE: The link has since changed to http://slick.ninjacave.com/

Answer (score 4):

A Java binding to SDL can be found here:

http://sdljava.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 3):

[Processing.org](http://processing.org/) has some good easy-to-use 2D stuff (and 3D). It has a [PApplet](http://dev.processing.org/reference/core/javadoc/processing/core/PApplet.html) class that implements Applet from AWT together with a bunch of useful operations and works well together with [Java2D](http://java.sun.com/products/java-media/2D/index.jsp).

If you just want to mess around with 2d graphics it has a "sketchpad IDE" where you don't need to put it in your java IDE if you just want to experiment with it.

Answer (score 0):

[Piccolo](http://code.google.com/p/piccolo2d/) can be a good choice for drawing graphics. It is a 2D graphics toolkit that supports zoomable user interface. Available for both Java and .Net.